# How to check the VPN setting created by an app on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, network, jailbreak, vpn

Many VPN apps would create VPN profiles on the iOS device. Unlike VPN profiles create by the user, they cannot be edited, and therefore the user cannot see the setting of said profile. With a jailbroken device, is there a way to hunt down such profile and read the setting in file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need to use OpenSSH at all whatsoever. The VPN settings are saved in /var/preferneces/com.apple.networkextension.plist file. Open it with a text editor. It's not encrypted. The passwords are saved in the keychain instead of inside this file. You cannot access the keychain on an iOS device and decrypt it easily but you can do it over a macbook that shares the keychain with your iOS device (if you enabled it). Type in your master password to view the saved passwords.

Comment: How do you read this folder without a jailbroken device?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes you can on a jailbroken iPhone using an app called OpenSSH.**

It will allow you access to all the system files and in normally conditions you can simple change the extension to .txt and open it with textedit for example.

**What you’ll need:**

- A jailbroken iPhone/iPod Touch with Cydia installed.
- OpenSSH Cydia Package.
- Wi-Fi and Internet access on the device.
- Mac/PC on the same Wi-Fi connection
- Suitable FTP/SSH clients like Cyberduck, Transmit etc.

Here is the [guide on CultofMac](http://www.cultofmac.com/32134/access-your-iphone-file-system-with-ssh-jailbreak-superguide/)

Also a link to the [OpenSSH Cydia Package](https://cydia.saurik.com/package/openssh/)

**Basic Instructions:**

1. install the OpenSSH package

   - (click, Install, Confirm, Close, Back)
2. open Wi-Fi from Settings
3. click your network's
4. read the "IP Address" field

   - (example: 192.168.1.100)
5. open Terminal on desktop

   - (open Spotlight, search for "Terminal")
   - Or if you're on Windows, you can use a desktop terminal application such as PuTTY(http://www.putty.org/).
6. run "ssh root@[insert IP Address]"

   - (example: ssh root@192.168.1.100)
7. wait a few minutes (just once)

   - (it's generating some crypto keys)
8. accept new computer host key

   - (if it doesn't ask you, that's fine)
9. log in with password "alpine"

   - (you should change this now)

Comment: This is just an instruction of the basic tool OpenSSH. How do you use OpenSSH to read VPN setting created by an app on an iOS device?

Comment: @JamesWayne That depends on the app. Once you have access to the filesystem, you can search for it. I have no idea where it is located, but you should find it on your own. If you want some help, you have to provide a lot more information (like the app and whatever you have found and the file structure). Also, even if you do find the settings, I'm sure you won't find how to parse the file and make sense of those. They may be in SQLite3, JSON, plaintext, yalm, csv ... And the files may be even encrypted! I have no idea and only the developers of the app could say (**IF** it is possible!).